# react js issue occurred with Link tag

Tags: reactjs

I am using Link button in my react application. According to my requirement I disable/enable it after check condition. all working well. but there is a error in my console log. but my disable/enable is working.

```
<Link onClick={
              row.values.STATUS == "Ok" ? (e) => e.preventDefault() : ""
            }
            className={row.values.STATUS == "Ok" ? "disabled-inv" : ""}
            to={{ pathname: "/app/createinvoice", state: row.values }}
          >
            Action
          </Link>
```

error is as below

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXd0v.png)

Comment: Error message says `onClick` prop doesn't accept strings, only functions. `row.values.STATUS == "Ok" ? (e) => e.preventDefault() : ""` <= there is the string. And please post the error message here, not a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says `onClick` prop doesn't accept `string`s, only `function`s. You can update your `onClick`, just pass a function and check the `row.values.STATUS` in there:

```
<Link
  onClick={(e) => {
    if (row.values.STATUS == 'Ok') {
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      // do something else if `STATUS` is not `Ok`
    }
  }}
>
  Action
</Link>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string to onClick. You should declare a new onClick function and pass it on onClick attribute like below.

```
const onClick= (e) => {

if (row.values.STATUS == "Ok"){
e.preventDefault();}
}

onClick={onClick}
```